# What is the difference between a crash and freeze?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I took a look in the developer's console and saw for the first time a freeze report rather than a crash. A crash is easy to define the breaking point from the stack trace. It normally led to a class/method being incorrectly defined or implemented.

However I have never encountered a freeze. Since Google made the effort to make the distinction in the dev console, what is the distinction?

From a general point of view obviously a crash is a force close. But does a freeze simply slow down the user experience without a force close? What are the technical differences? Is there a different method to address a freeze when compared to a crash?

Edit: added example stack traces.

Here is an example of a **Crash** The stack trace is very specific pointing to a line of failure.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ZoomControls
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.createContainer(ZoomButtonsController.java:262)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.<init>(ZoomButtonsController.java:211)
at android.webkit.WebView.getZoomButtonsController(WebView.java:6313)
at android.webkit.WebView.startDrag(WebView.java:5700)
at android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:5428)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
```

Here is an example **Freeze** the stack trace is less specific not pointing to a direct line or activity at fault.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027550 self=0xcfc0
  | sysTid=2076 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=-1345006240
  | schedstat=( 30958526727 7780212297 24174 )
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateScaledBitmap(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:556)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:722)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1998)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:389)


     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
      at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1702)
  at com.e3h.usmcknowledge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:132)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1037)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It might be wise to add the Stack Trace so we may be sure before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no formal definition. But broadly speaking, a crash occur when an uncontrolled error happens. Freeze is when an application stops to respond to any event (for example an infinite loop) but no actual error happens (no exception thrown).

Comment: So does that mean that a freeze is necessarily my own app's fault or perhaps the user has a lot of background processes of a lower end phone?

Comment: A freeze could be caused by your own app, by another app, or by the operating system itself.  Running a lot of (well-behaved) apps might cause an increasing amount of sluggishness but shouldn't cause a permanent freeze.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a crash is an unexpected, abnormal exit.  A freeze or hang occurs when the program (or the entire system) stops responding entirely.